# Is it possible to connect to the SugarCRM database without using a skin?

Tags: customization, sugarcrm, skin

I have made a design of a UI and have web page now. Now I want to use and modify information from the SugarCRM database. Is there a way to connect my web page to the database?

The UI needs to combine information from multiple databases, so making a custom skin and import this in SugarCRM does not look like an option.

Is there a way to connect the dots? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a typical SugarCRM setup, yes you can setup a simple PHP script that connects to multiple databases and renders the fields you need. What Databases are you trying to connect to??

However, the recommended way to access your SugarCRM data would be to do so through the REST API. This will better ensure/protect the integrity of your sugarCRM instance. It will require a little setup up front but well worth the time. The last thing you want is external scripts altering your sugar instance data and corrupting your database. Also it will most likely take you just as long if not longer, to decipher the sugarCRM database schema and and write your queries. Your script can call the REST API and get whatever data you need to make available.

So yes, you can query the Sugar DB directly through a PHP script (if you know what you're doing), but it is best to use the REST API and have it return the objects/data you need rather than mess with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just translating your design into a new theme in Sugar. Check out the /themes directory for an existing theme. You could use that as a starting point.

Otherwise, you'd need to use the REST API to redo all of the logic already done in Sugar. Depends on what your requirements are.